# Постановка запятой после вводного выражения

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

*Мягко говоря () озадаченный, Васенька вышел во двор.*
Следует ли ставить запятую после вводного выражения в данном случае? Если нет, то каким правилом нужно пользоваться? Из-за "тесной связи" вводной части и идущего за ней слова не поднимается рука поставить запятую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обособления определения в этом случае  можно использовать тире:

***Мягко говоря, озадАченный** – Васенька вышел во двор.*

1. Обычно обособление согласованного определения в начале предложения делается для его актуализации, подчеркивания  (например, при дополнительном обстоятельственном значении).

В этом числе имя собственное  в качестве определяемого существительного способствует обособлению.

2. Но в данном случае вместо запятой используется тире **в связи с наличием вводного слова**, отнесенного к обособленному определению.
3. Интонация здесь особая, пауза только слегка подчеркнута, поэтому основным ударением выделено определение.Условно можно считать, что это **грамматическая** запятая, которая не отражается интонационно.

Розенталь, § 18. Обособленные определения. Согласованные определения, пункт.6  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109